# Route is not triggerd with Attribute Routing and FromUri

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, routeattribute

I want to trigger the below route with this url:

```
http://localhost:66777/api/productdetails?articlegroup=1&producedat=2012-01-01
```

What is wrong with my - I guess - Route attribute?

```
[Route("api/productdetails/{articlegroup:int}/{producedat:datetime}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProductDetails([FromUri] ProductDetailsRequestDTO dto)
{
    //...
}

public class ProductDetailsRequestDTO
{
    public int ArticleGroup { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProducedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route templates support only the 'path' and not the query string. In your above example, you have `articlegroup` and `producedat` as route variables on the 'path' where as your are sending the data for these in the query string. Since the route template match fails to find this data in the path, you probably are getting a 404 - which is expected.

Comment: You answered the Why, but what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Well, do you want the users to send the data in the path? if not just remove that from the route template

Comment: thanks I removed the query string from the route attribute. Then it works.